# Why my DOS interface will flash across when I run a cpp file in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: c++

Just as you see in the title? I have been confused about that for a long while.

Comment: What was in your .cpp file?

Comment: Just a hello world for test...

Comment: There's an expectation on Stack Overflow that questions should have effort put into them, they should be clear, and they should avoid an excessively chatty style. A body of "see title" is likely to get a question closed with downvotes, as has happened here - you might have expended days of conscientious effort, but we can see no evidence of it. Thus: more detail and more question effort = upvotes and more answer effort.

Answer (score 1):

In many windowing systems, a console window is opened up when your program starts executing.  When your program stops executing the window disappears.  This regardless to any output sent to the console.

If your program is quick, the console will "flash" by.

If you want your console window to stay for a while, you will need to pause execution.  My idiom is:

```
std::cout << "\nPaused.  Press Enter to continue.\n";
std::cin.ignore(10000, '\n');
```

I don't use `system("Pause")` because not all operating systems have a `Pause` command.

Comment: "Flash" again,although I have taken your advice by adding the code! I thought something wrong must have happened in other places....

Comment: @SleighTroyete: if the answer was helpful, please click on the check mark.